# How do Ruby programmers do type checking?

Tags: ruby, oop, duck-typing

Since there is no type in ruby, how do Ruby programmers make sure a function receives correct arguments? Right now, I am repeating `if object.kind_of`/`instance_of` statements to check and raise runtime errors everywhere, which is ugly. There must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Why do you need to make sure the input is of a specific type? Functions do what they're told and shouldn't really be forced to type check.

Comment: @Blender Eg. setNextNode(link) .In this function if I don't have a type check anything can be passed in...Am doing a assignment now and I have been told to do type checking and make sure runtime safety.

Comment: @cjk: It's too bad that your teacher doesn't quite understand that there are trade offs between statically and dynamically typed languages, trying to turn one into the other.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I've added the duck-typing tag to the question.

Comment: @EdS. It's too bad I can't downvote the teacher. I won't downvote this question merely because someone has a bad teacher, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ruby is, of course, dynamically typed.

Thus the method documentation determines the type contract; the type-information is moved from the formal type-system to the [informal type specification in the] method documentation. I mix generalities like "acts like an array" and specifics such as "is a string". The caller should only expect to work with the *stated* types.

*If the caller violates this contract then anything can happen*. The method need not worry: it was used incorrectly.

In light of the above, I *avoid* checking for a specific type and *avoid* trying to create overloads with such behavior.

Unit-tests can *help* ensure that the contract works for expected data.

Comment: @cjk While this is a good paradigm to follow, it still doesn't answer the question. I suggest that you accept sawa's answer instead.

Answer (score 24):

My personal way, which I am not sure if it a recommended way in general, is to type-check and do other validations once an error occurs. I put the type check routine in a rescue block. This way, I can avoid performance loss when correct arguments are given, but still give back the correct error message when an error occurs.

```
def foo arg1, arg2, arg3
  ...
  main_routine
  ...
rescue
  ## check for type and other validations
  raise "Expecting an array: #{arg1.inspect}" unless arg1.kind_of?(Array)
  raise "The first argument must be of length 2: #{arg1.inspect}" unless arg1.length == 2
  raise "Expecting a string: #{arg2.inspect}" unless arg2.kind_of?(String)
  raise "The second argument must not be empty" if arg2.empty?
  ...
  raise "This is `foo''s bug. Something unexpected happened: #{$!.message}"
end
```

Suppose in the `main_routine`, you use the method `each` on `arg1` assuming that `arg1` is an array. If it turns out that it is something else, to which `each` is not defined, then the bare error message will be something like `method each not defined on ...`, which, from the perspective of the user of the method `foo`, might be not helpful. In that case, the original error message will be replaced by the message `Expecting an array: ...`, which is much more helpful.

Comment: The problem with this though, is the *real* error could be masked due to one of the other issues being picked up. So, while it might *also* be an issue, it might not be related to what was actually raised. If explicit type checking is going to be done, do it *first*, not on recovery.

Comment: Why do you use `#{arg1}` instead of `#{arg1.inspect}`? Or more specificially, `"Expecting a string: #{arg2}"` instead of `"Expecting a string: #{arg2.inspect}"`?

Comment: @pst That can be avoided by putting another `raise` at the end as I edited. If an error is raised internal to `foo` but all the validation passes, then it is either the case that validation check was not enough or there is a bug internal to `foo`.

Comment: I'm still not a fan of this approach, even though I did up-vote it. I don't consider exceptions for this manner of human consumption.

Comment: I really like this solution. To me it seems quite elegant.

Comment: While it saves time when the arguments aren't incorrect, you could potentially waste a lot of time processing incorrect arguments until the system actually raises an exception.

Comment: @SpaceGhost Passing wrong arguments are supposed to be detected by the test phase, and should not be left in production, so slow speed does not matter.

Comment: @sawa That isn't always true or possible, but I agree that it is a nice world to live in.

Answer (score 9):

If a method has a reason to exist, it will be called.

If reasonable tests are written, everything will be called.

And if every method is called, then every method will be type-checked.

Don't waste time putting in type checks that may unnecessarily constrain callers and will just duplicate the run-time check anyway. Spend that time writing tests instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use raise at the beginning of the method to add manual type checking, simple and effective:

```
def foo(bar)
    raise TypeError, "You called foo without the bar:String needed" unless bar.is_a? String
    bar.upcase
end
```

Best way when you don't have much parameters, also a recommendation is to use keyword arguments available on ruby 2+ if you have multiple parameters and watch for its current/future implementation details, they are improving the situation, giving the programmer a way to see if the value is nil.

plus: you can use a custom exception

```
class NotStringError < TypeError
   def message 
     "be creative, use metaprogramming ;)"
#...
raise NotStringError
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) approach, with the [contracts](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby) ruby gem. I find it quite nice.